How to get WMS filtered by metadata
I have six rasters in TIFF format and shapefile metadata with six shapes matching the rasters with some properties.
I would like to create webapp to display specific rasters depending on properties.
Example usage:
Using form I create WFS filtered request for specific shapes.
Then i can make request to WMS to display rasters that match filter.
What I can do:
I can create WMS Image Mosaic layer using GeoServer so I can display rasters.
I can create WFS service with shapes and metadata.
How can I connect it?
Long time ago I used ArcGIS Server. I put OBJECT_ID in metadata.
Then I queried WMS rasters by IMAGES parameter in mosaic dataset.
I don't have too much experience with spatial data.

If you want to only display specific rasters why put them into a mosaic? If you are fixed on a mosaic then read up about DIMENSIONS for WMS

If you only want to search by shape, then there's no need to have a WFS, you just need to use a modified bounding box, which is part of  the WMS specification.    How you handle the TIFFs,  mosaic, group layer, individual layers in the WMS, will depend on whether the tiffs overlap.
